# decoupling from future APIs - first-timer discovering need for dependency injection

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns, repository-pattern

I have a naive question about OOP design patterns. This is over-architecture, but I need a recommendation, not judgment. Suppose you have a class hierarchy dictated by "business requirements". So, you've got a deeper version of `Pizza : Freight`, `Flowers : Freight` and a `TonOfBricks : Freight` and you've got an `IDispatchService<F> where F : Freight` and an `IDeliveryService<F> where F : Freight`.

Now suppose that different `IDeliveryService` implementations want different information about the freight. What they want *does not parallel your class hierarchy*, and you have no clue what delivery service (ie. API) you're gonna use in a month for what kind of parcel. Furthermore, you may have enough information to send one pizza through a vacuum tube, but maybe not the next.

Now you realized that you can also hire people to deliver your pizzas on rollerblades, but you'll need to specify the center of mass of every object delivered this way or else insurance will kill you. Do you implement it as an `IDeliveryService<Pizza>`? Are you also adding a new interface `IHasCenterOfMass` and maybe implementing as `IDeliveryService<IHasCenterOfMass>`? If so, how's the dispatcher gonna like it? Are you adding a relation to your database for center of mass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is not to violate the substitution principle which states that every derived should be changeable with another derived as long as they share the same base class/interface. Therefore my recommendation would be to make your services accept a XXXServiceInformation instance which contains the specific information for that required service and knows how to potentially read it from source. Example:

```
interface IDeliveryService<F> where F : Freight
{
    void Deliver();
}

class RollerBladesDeliveryService<F> : IDeliveryService<F> where F: Freight
{
    public RollerBladesDeliveryService(RollerBladesDeliveryInformation<F> information){ ... }

    void Deliver() { ... }
}

class RollerBladesDeliveryInformation<F> where F: Freight
{
    public RollerBladesDeliveryInformation(F freight, double centerOfMass) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Thank you -- that's exactly where I was headed, but where would you put instances of XXXDeliveryInformation?

Comment: @nik.shornikov - Not sure if i understand your question,logically you save the information instance in the destined service. Where you create the information instance is where your fundamental problem lies. Since each service requires an information object, the difficulty gets to the point where you need to create those services in an abstract manner. Better said, you need factories that are smart enough to in this case, determine the centerOfMass for each freight. That can be difficult.

Comment: Thanks. You answered what I was asking, which was about the context of the constructor being called (ie. where's the "deliveryinfo" argument coming from).

Answer (score 3):

Plan for what you know going to far down the what if rabbit hole will only create code you will never use. If you know of 3 Delivery Services that can implement IDeliveryService great if not then you might be able to make a generic interface but you might find that it might not fit what you need in the future.

Comment: I can't disagree. When I started thinking about serializing untyped "service information" instances in the database, I realized "rabbit hole" applies, but I asked anyway. Some good responses.

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose you have a class hierarchy dictated by "business requirements". So, you've got a deeper version of Pizza : Freight, Flowers : Freight and a TonOfBricks : Freight and you've got an IDispatchService where F : Freight and an IDeliveryService where F : Freight

Stop right that. That is not correct OOP. Pizza and flowers is not a freight. They are contents in a freight. The distinction is very important since it generates cleaner code with a single responsibility.

> Now suppose that different IDeliveryService implementations want different information about the freight

Not a problem as long as each `IPizzaDeliveryService` implementation requires the same kind of information.

a general delivery routine would look like:

```
foreach (var freight in queue)
{
    var service = GetServiceFor(freight.ContentType);
    service.Dispatch(freight);
}
```

**Update**

```
public interface IFreight
{
    IFreightContent Content{get;}
    Type ContentType { get { return Content.GetType() }}
    PostalAddress DeliveryAddress {get;}
}


public interface IFreightContent
{
}

// we don't just deliver the pizza, do we? ;)
public class PizzaBox : IFreightContent
{
}
```

Comment: The first point wouldn't have saved me from asking, but how you envision the delivery routine is very helpful to me. Is ContentType a Type property or just an enum? If you unpack that at all, I'd be grateful.